# Error with NSNumber Category because of NSCFNumber

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, categories, nsnumber, class-cluster

I am using WSDL2OBJC for an OS X project.  Part of the code generated by WSDL2OBJC adds a category to NSNumber.  While I'm using the code I attempt to call the new method on an NSNumber and get an error:

```
+[NSCFNumber xmlNodeForDoc:elementName:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff70b6b8c8
```

I've read that NSNumber is a class cluster and has private classes and that NSCFNumber is the class for ints.  How can I get this to work?  I can't add the category to NSCFNumber since it is a private class.  This same code works for an iPhone project that I have.

Comment: I got this working.  It looks like the issue was a memory problem.  I was passing the NSNumber to an [NSInvocation setArgument: atIndex:].  It worked in the iPhone app because I was creating a variable and passing it by reference.  I believe it wasn't working for me because I removed creating a separate var and just did [NSNumber numberWithInt:].

Comment: Glad you solved it! Please consider taking a moment to post the solution as an answer and accept it; this way the question will not show up as "Unanswered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. It looks like the issue was a memory problem. I was passing the `NSNumber` to an `[NSInvocation setArgument: atIndex:]`. It worked in the iPhone app because I was creating a variable and passing it by reference. I believe it wasn't working for me because I removed creating a separate var and just did `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]`.

Comment: I am facing same issue, but cant resolve it. Can you please explain what was it that was causing the issue?

I have tried, [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:] autorelease] as well as [NSNumber numberWithInt:], but as soon as setArgument:atIndex: is done, the retain count for same becomes -1.